# trying to login using php mysql

Tags: php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../admin/css/styles.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>


<body>
   <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-2"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 login-box">
                <div class="col-lg-12 login-key">
                    <i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 login-title">
                    ADMIN PANEL
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-12 login-form">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 login-form">
                        <form action="" method="POST">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="form-control-label">USERNAME</label>
                                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="form-control-label">PASSWORD</label>
                                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" i>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-12 loginbttm">
                                <div class="col-lg-6 login-btm login-text">
                                    <!-- Error Message -->
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6 login-btm login-button">
                                    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

  </body>
</html>


<?php

include 'db.php';



if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
$db=mysqli_select_db($conn,"admin");    
 echo   $sql= "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    
       $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
       $rows=mysqli_num_rows($result);
       
       if($rows == 1){
        echo 'hi';
       }
       else{
        echo 'failed';
       }
}
?>
```

I created database and inserted username and password. Database connected successfully. This is the code i have written for login page. I am entering username and password. I echo  the query, its showing username and password but not echoing 'hi'. Its echoing failed. Where is the error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is core php not codeigniter.

Comment: Before if statement add `var_dump($rows)` and remove `echo` from `$sql`

Comment: the password isn't stored plaintext so the `password='$password'` part of your query likely always fails

Answer (score 3):

It is because you're `echo`ing the query not actually executing it.

remove this

> echo   $sql= "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";

add this

> $sql= "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";

A couple of points to improve the query,

- Never `SELECT *`, It's bad practice, instead mention column names
- Use PDO or even better a PDO library (IMO)

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove `echo` which is in front of `$sql`.
2. Check if you are writing the correct `$username` and `$password` in database admin field.
3. echo the `$rows` variable. Check if it is different than 1.
4. Not related to your problem but good to fix; move your PHP code above everything on the code.

Comment: on 3rd point I'd use `var_dump()` or `print_r()` instead of `echo` and I completely agree with you on 4th point

Comment: In his case, $rows variable holds the number of records:
$rows=mysqli_num_rows($result);

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have two couple of equal username and password in database o it return 2 instead of one. `echo $rows` to check it.